# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this code in a class for the connection to the database.

```
package fullhouse;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FullhouseDB {

    private static Connection databaseConnectie;


    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if(databaseConnectie == null){
                String connectString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fullhouse";
                try {
                     databaseConnectie = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, "root", "2002112735");
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FullhouseDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            } 

        return databaseConnectie;

    }
```

And I get this error:

```
dec 29, 2014 5:05:49 PM fullhouse.FullhouseDB getConnection
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fullhouse
```

I've checked the username and password, the connection of database services, and all is correct.

Comment: Is the driver JAR for the MySQL database in your classpath?

Comment: Your tag says sql-server but url says mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the driver class using:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

And then define connect string url.

```
String connectString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fullhouse";
```

Answer (score 0):

First you take mysql driver file from the url below url

http://projectshub.in/softwares/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

than add this driver file to your project lib folder.